# Did Hogwarts have a "physical education" style class?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

A comment I made on another question got me thinking...

In the movies at least, and from character descriptions in the books, most of the students at Hogwarts appear to be in good (if not great) physical condition. I imagine that running around the grounds, moving from class to class, etc. helps with that. But I'm curious -- do the books contain any mention of physical education style classes, similar to what you might see at a U.S. high school or a British state school? Or for that matter, are there any descriptions of students "working out" (e.g., weight lifting or jogging)?

Note: I've found questions describing [sports at Hogwarts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97265/does-hogwarts-have-sports-if-youre-not-in-a-quidditch-team) and [non-Magical course offerings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7436/does-hogwarts-teach-non-magical-classes), but neither IMO seem to fully answer the question.

Comment: The real question is: Why do muggle schools have it? Except for the last two years, I've learned nothing useful in those lessons. And it isn't enough to have children move enough.

Comment: @Fabian - It used to be that they'd get you to exert yourself and take part in competitive sports

Comment: Some of the kids at least get chased around by masked terrorists on a semi-regular basis, which must be good for them on some level.

Comment: @TheDarkLord Hogwarts should really reward you for your contributions to their students' physical activity!

Comment: Yes, the magical equivalent was the dueling club

Comment: I've been convinced that they all stay magically slim somehow. Given that there are unlimited amounts of food regular feasting and bountiful sweets. Almost none of the students are overweight, this does not seem likely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## No, the only form of physical activity classes is flying lessons.

None of the classes at Hogwarts are based on physical activity, including the electives, except for flying lessons (and the Quidditch teams). All forms of "official" physical exercise mentioned are related to either flying or Quidditch, like Oliver Wood's training program.

The students would get a lot of exercise simply getting around Hogwarts to their various classes in different locations in the fairly large castle.

Comment: The last paragraph makes me crack up lol

Comment: To be honest, in flying I think the broom's doing most of the work. ;)

Comment: @TheDarkLord - ever tried riding a horse for a couple of hours? The horse "does most of the work". In theory. **It's bloody tiring!**