# What did Madam Hooch do all day?

Tags: harry-potter

Far be it from me to accuse the Hogwarts teachers of not working hard enough but I struggle to see how Flying Teacher is really a full-time occupation. As far as I can tell, Madame Hooch has two main jobs:

- Teaching the first-year students how to fly (classes aren't mentioned after *The Philosopher's Stone* so I'm assuming that they are only for first-years).
- Refereeing the six inter-House Quidditch matches over the course of the year.

I would've expected that this would merit a part-time role with Hooch perhaps coming to stay at Hogwarts for the duration of the flying lessons (which maybe lasted two or three months) and then coming back at weekends when there was a match to referee.

However, *The Prisoner of Azkaban* seems to imply that she's there the whole year.

> "Well, goodness knows, I'd like to see us win the Cup at last...but all the same, Potter...I'd be happier if a teacher were present. I'll ask Madam Hooch to oversee your training sessions."
>
> *(Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 9, Grim Defeat)*.

She's still there later in the year when Wood has increased the number of training sessions to five a week.

> Madam Hooch, who was still overseeing Gryffindor practices to keep an eye on Harry, was just as impressed with the Firebolt as everyone else had been.
>
> *(Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 13, Gryffindor verses Ravenclaw)*

**So is Madam Hooch a permanent resident teacher like the others? Is there any canon evidence that she has additional responsibilities beyond those that I've laid out here?**

Comment: I have been wondering about her as well. Maybe she was the intuitive go-to replacement because she doesn't have anything to do 9 months a year. :-)

Comment: Maybe she lives in hogsmeade so it's not too much trouble for her to come out for quidditch matches and the occasional practice?

Comment: As your quotes suggest, she may assist all practices and help the different hogwart's teams to improve...

Comment: We dont see 90% of Harrys day-to-day schedule at Hogwarts, so its not outside reason that there are lots of boring lessons we don't see, including flying lessons.  After all,  I learned to swim when I was 5, but I still had swimming lessons for the next 10 years of my life thanks to the various schools I went to...

Comment: Did all the first years attend flying lessons at the same time? I think most classes went by House, with some mixed (only to setup tension between Harry and Draco). At any rate she may have more than one class a day.

Comment: @Skooba, Gryffindors and Slytherins learned together, which implies that there were two first-year classes of around 50. So she probably taught two classes a week.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56725/to-what-extent-are-flying-lessons-provided-at-hogwarts

Comment: I always assimed she was the gym/phys. ed. teacher.

Comment: @JoeL. She probably would be if there were one, but magic kids don't seem to need exercise…

Comment: She drank, of course. Where did you think she got her name from?

Comment: @terdon Another parallelity/similarity between her and Trelawney!

Comment: @terdon Her real name was Professor Smith, but everybody just called her by the nickname, derived from the only potion she knew how to make. But what a potion it was! Liquid luck, liquid happines, veritaserum, fireball, stupefy, and Avada Kedavra To The Liver, all rolled into one.

Comment: maybe she also gave private lessons to those who took an interest in quidditch but were average players?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

## She was likely not a full-time teacher

Rolanda Hooch doesn’t appear much in the books (even less in the films) and there is no proper Pottermore article on her (only a characters-from-the-films page, which isn’t by Rowling), so there is—to my knowledge—no canon information to answer this decisively. The way I’ve always read things in my head, however, matches what [dunraven’s comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126073/what-did-madam-hooch-do-all-day#comment315018_126073) above says, that she was probably not a permanent, full-time teacher at Hogwarts.

There are a few things that hint at this, though only circumstantially:

#### 1. Her age might indicate retirement

If we accept the [*Philosopher’s Stone* video game](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Philosopher%27s_Stone_(video_game)) (sorry, Wiki link) as canon, then Rolanda Hooch’s broom was singed during the Great War (i.e., the First World War). Presuming that she had left Hogwarts before she had anything to do with the War, she would have been born no later than 1900, making her at least 90 years old at the time of the Harry Potter books. (The fact that she falls asleep during one of the Quidditch practice sessions that she oversees *may* be an indicator of somewhat advanced age.)

As such, it would seem plausible that she has retired from any actual, full-time teaching career she may have had (whatever she may have taught), and is now more loosely connected to Hogwarts, coming in to teach flying lessons to first-years and oversee various other broom-related events, such as Quidditch training and matches, when called for. If she lives in Hogsmeade, this should be fairly easy to arrange even on short notice. In fact, as pointed out in the comments, it should be fairly easy to arrange even if she doesn’t live in Hogsmeade: she could easily apparate from more or less anywhere in the country to Hogsmeade and walk the short distance from there into the school grounds. Communication doesn’t seem to be an issue either: both owls and Floo network communication seem to work very well (when Umbridge isn’t Headmaster, that is).

There’s also nothing in the parts quoted in the question here that goes against this: McGonagall only says, “I’ll ask Madam Hooch to oversee your training sessions”, which would still be perfectly logical if Madam Hooch was in frequent communication with the school and on call to come by for such things.

#### 2. She’s never referred to as *Professor*

We know that she has an office at Hogwarts,<sup>1</sup> so I would say she must be considered a member of staff (though having an office doesn’t necessarily make her a *full-time* member of staff, of course). To a certain degree, the students probably also think of her as ‘one of the teachers’. But it is notable that she is consistently referred to as *Madam* Hooch, never *Professor* Hooch.

The title *Madam* seems to be a fairly generic term of respect towards witches in general in the Potterverse: it is used with various witches like Madam Rosmerta and Madam (Amelia) Bones, for example. It is also, importantly, used for the only other two *non-teaching female members of staff at Hogwarts* we know of: Madam Pince the librarian, and Madam Pomfrey the healer. (I don’t quite consider Mrs Norris *staff*.)

All the members of staff that *teach*, however, are consistently referred to as *Professor*, regardless of gender: Professor McGonagall, Professor Flitwick, Professor Snape, Professor Marchbanks, Professor Trelawney, etc. The only exception to this is Firenze and, well, he’s a centaur. During the first class with him, we even see that Parvati Patil seems rather unsure of what to call him:

> “Please – er – sir –” said Parvati breathlessly
>   <sub>*Order of the Phoenix*, ch. 27: “The Centaur and the Sneak”</sub>

#### 3. Her general absence

Finally, there is the simple fact that, apart from the flying lessons and the Quidditch training/matches where she appears, *we never see Madam Hooch at all in the books*. All the other teachers that play an actual part in the book make random little appearances throughout, showing that even if there aren’t any actual scenes with them, they’re still around. But no one ever runs into Madam Hooch in the hallway or anything like that, and even when something happens that involves most of the teachers in one way or another (like Fred and George spreading mayhem before flying off, at which point we see Flitwick wondering if he has the *authority*, McGonagall telling Peeves a chandelier unscrews the other way, etc.), she is absent.<sup>2</sup>

The only other teacher in a somewhat similar situation would be Professor Trelawney, who never shows up outside her own rather limited teaching schedule either (except for a few select scenes: her near-sacking, the Christmas lunch, her sherry-hiding foray, and of course the Battle of Hogwarts—where Madam Hooch is also absent, incidentally). Unlike Madam Hooch, though, who is very much an outdoorsy person and would likely to bonkers if she had to stay cooped up inside a castle (not to mention an office in a castle) all the time, Professor Trelawney is more than happy to remain in her solitarily stifling tower chambers fiddling with her crystal ball and sherry bottles, so there’s less to wonder about there, and her nigh-complete absence is easier to explain than Madam Hooch’s would be.

The fact that Madam Hooch is absent from pretty much *everything* but her actual (conjectured) teaching duties is a good indication that she simply *isn’t there* the rest of the time.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> From *Chamber of Secrets*, ch. 10 ‘The Rogue Bludger’: “But the Bludgers have been locked in Madam Hooch’s office since our last practice, and there was nothing wrong with them then …’ said Wood, anxiously.”</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> Even at the Start of Term Feast in *Philosopher’s Stone* where Dumbledore says that students wishing to try out for Quidditch teams should contact Madam Hooch, she is never mentioned as being present, though it’s possible she was.</sup>

Comment: Yes, we know they have substitute teachers on call, so why not part-time too?  And as for Professor Trelawney, I rather think she filled her time with sherry rather than with her crystal ball. (Her, um, 'excesses' in the 5th year didn't come out of nowhere...)

Comment: @davidbak I think she'd be quite up to the task of combining the two. ;-)

Comment: So the use of adjunct faculty has bled over into the wizarding world?

Comment: Does it matter if she lives nearby, in Hogsmeade? She could apparate there from anywhere in the UK.

Comment: Apparently the role was diminished in the films because Zoe Wannamaker (who played her in PS only) complained about the pay and wasn't invited back. Apparently.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Good point—my Muggle mindset had me in a box there.

Comment: Just a detail: in this phrase it's written "this is so even if she doesn’t LOVE in Hogsmeade". I know it's just a scratch, but it's funny. Maybe you should edit the post and correct it. However, great answer, very detailed!

Comment: @Eithne Ah! The trials of typing on a phone. Something always slips through the cracks. _Go raibh maith agat, a Eithne_ (going by your user name alone here). :-)

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @Eithne That’s Irish, in which language _Eithne_ is a girl’s name of obscure origin (don’t believe sites that tell you it means ‘kernel’—that’s a different word), originally the name of a goddess in Irish mythology.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, very nice! I'm not Irish (I chose this nickname because it's beautiful and has a nice meaning) but I think it is a very interesting language. Thanks!

Comment: @Eithne - Consider posting on [our usernames thread](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7371/the-many-usernames-of-sffse).

Answer (score 12):

High schools in the US (ages 15-18 or so) have "Drivers' Education" classes, or at least they did when I was in HS, where they teach you to drive a car, usually sometime close to when you turn legal driving age (16 where I grew up).

I can see a similar need at Hogwarts for educating young witches and wizards about safely operating a broom. I can't recall anything from the books beyond what you mentioned, but I can imagine it would be at least a part-time job.

The Drivers' Ed teacher at my school was a full-time instructor. He was also the soccer coach, so there's precedent for that as well!

Comment: How big was your school?

Comment: Drivers' Education is arguably more resemblant of the _apparition lessons_ that sixth-grade Hogwarts students can take.

Comment: @RogueJedi When I attended, my school had about 1600 students: not very big by US public HS standards. Admittedly, that's a lot more than Hogwarts, which seemed to have about 40 students in each year, for a total of about 300. But their funding model is very different, if that means anything.

Comment: I'd be wary about comparing a US high school to Hogwarts given that the author has spent the majority of her life in Britain (where secondary school is very different in terms of structure and curriculum). Driving lessons are not commonly part of British school life, they are typically taught separately by specialised driving schools.